# binding data across objects in Java (non-UI)

Tags: java, oop, data-binding, binding, logic

I'm not sure what the term for the result I'm trying to get is, however the concept of **binding** seems to come closest.

In Java I'm trying to figure out how to (without an observer pattern) have members in one object automatically change when a certain member in another object changes.

I see binding being used for UI/backend data binding (with Swing) but I don't see anything about doing it between non-UI objects.

Comment: Only way to make it possible without observer pattern is hard-wiring the code!

Comment: But you *should* use the observer pattern in such a case, otherwise you couple the objects, so stop being a naughty boy and do it properly! :)